# Object assigned in base class does not change the child class

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I want to create a base class with initial data like below:

```
export abstract class Entity {
    constructor(data?) {
        if (data) {
            Object.assign(this, data);
        }
    }
}
```

with a child class like below:

```
export class Filter extends Entity{
      show = true
      constructor(filter?: Partial<Filter>) {
        super(filter);
    }
}
```

The issue I am facing is that when I create an object like this `new Filter({show:false})`, I get the following result:

```
Filter {show: true}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-a4kyff)

The object in base class did not reflect the values in child class. Any thoughts why is this happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens because, once the code is transpiled, the child class property assignment happens **after** the parent constructor has been invoked, you can see that by using the typescript playground and set, in the options, to target `ES5`.

To make it shorter, the transpiled code will be the following:

```
"use strict";
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
    var extendStatics = function (d, b) {
        extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
            ({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array && function (d, b) { d.__proto__ = b; }) ||
            function (d, b) { for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p]; };
        return extendStatics(d, b);
    };
    return function (d, b) {
        extendStatics(d, b);
        function __() { this.constructor = d; }
        d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
    };
})();
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var Entity = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Entity(data) {
        if (data) {
            Object.assign(this, data);
        }
    }
    return Entity;
}());
exports.Entity = Entity;
var Filter = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    __extends(Filter, _super);
    function Filter(filter) {
        var _this = _super.call(this, filter) || this;
        _this.show = true;
        return _this;
    }
    return Filter;
}(Entity));
exports.Filter = Filter;
new Filter({ show: false });
```

As you can see, the relevant part is that, in the Filter's contructor, the `show` property is assigned **after** the parent constructor has been executed.

```
var Filter = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    __extends(Filter, _super);
    function Filter(filter) {
        var _this = _super.call(this, filter) || this;
        _this.show = true;
        return _this;
    }
    return Filter;
}(Entity));
```

To solve the issue, you should just redesign your code and make sure you assign the property in the constructor, instead in the class declaration, leaving the class declaration empty:

```
export abstract class Entity {
    constructor(data?) {
        if (data) {
          Object.assign(this, data);
        }
    }
}

export class Filter extends Entity{
      public show: boolean;
      constructor(filter?: Partial<Filter>) {
        super(filter);
        this.show = (this.show === undefined) ? true : this.show;
        console.log(this);
    }
}

new Filter({show:false}); // show is false
new Filter(); // show is true (default value)
```

Working code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-c4u557

Another possible approach is that `Entity` class should have a `show` property with a default value, but it doesn't seems like you want do that, from the hierarchy you've shown.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you've set `show` variable to `true` in your derived class. So it overrides the value of base class. To avoid this behavior you should just delete initialization value:

```
export class Filter extends Entity{
      show;
      constructor(filter?: Partial<Filter>) {
        super(filter);
        console.log('Filter', this)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved by adding a setTimeOut on the Object.assing like this:

```
constructor (data) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    Object.assing(this, data)
  }, 0)
}
```

It makes the assing at the finish of the javascript queue.
Or you can make a class decorator and do your logic overriding the constructor

```
function DecoratorName () {
  return function _DecoratorName<T extends {new (...args: any[]): {}}>(constr: T) {
    return class extends constr {
      constructor (...args: any[]) {
        // The logic inside here executes after child declaration 
        // and allows get no undefined on properties on 
        // Object.assing use
        super(...args)
        Object.assign(this, args[0].data)
      }
    }
  }
}

@DecoratorName()
class Example {

}
```